# Поиск и подсветка хеш-тегов в строке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имею следующий текст:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod       tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
>   ad minim veniam,          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo         consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse         cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non           proident, sunt in
>   culpa qui **#officia** deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. **#letsgo** **#xxx** **#socnet**

Мне надо его пропустить через preg_replace, а именно вытащить оттуда хэш-теги (#officia, #letsgo, #xxx, #socnet) и заключить их в ссылку

Написал следующую функцию:

```
function InsertHashTag($string)
{
    $template = "/#[^\s]+\b/iUm";
    $rep = "<a href='' class='hash'>$1</a>";
    preg_replace($template, $rep, $string);
    echo $string;
}
```

Но ничего не меняется. Ф-ция возвращает исходный результат. Подскажите, чего такое

Comment: Вы про плуг забыли. Либо замените `$1` на `$0`, либо определите в регулярке группу для замены через круглые скобки.

Comment: Без изменений...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме указанных замечаний в комментарии выше, хочу добавить, что preg_replace() не модифицирует строку. А в вашем примере именно на это и был сделан акцент: вы пытались вывести именно переменную $string, а не результат работы функции preg_replace().

```
function InsertHashTag($string) {
    $template = "~#([\S]+)~i";
    $rep = '<a href="" class="hash">$1</a>';
    return preg_replace($template, $rep, $string);
}


echo InsertHashTag('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui #officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. #letsgo #xxx #socnet');
```